# How to post to Google Measurement protocol using Python?

Tags: python, http, post, google-analytics

[Measurement protocol guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide)

I need an example of how a POST would look using Python.

Something like this, but working.

```
import httplib, urllib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google-analytics.com")
conn.request("POST", "v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXX-Y&cid=666&t=event&ec=game&ea=start&ev=0")
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just needed a URL:

```
conn.request("POST", "/collect", "v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXX-Y&cid=666&t=event&ec=game&ea=start&ev=0")
```

Or with a dictionary:

```
import httplib, urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({
    'v': 1,
    'tid': 'UA-XXXXXX-Y',
    'cid': '666',
    't': 'event',
    'ec': 'game',
    'ea': 'start',
    'ev': 0
})

connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.google-analytics.com')
connection.request('POST', '/collect', params)
```

Comment: Can you please trace this working example with fiddler http debugger and post the raw request and response? I would like to solve my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451738/universal-analytics-measurement-protocol-respond-200-ok-but-no-events-appers