# Universal Analytics Measurement Protocol respond 200 OK, but no events appers

Tags: http, google-analytics

I am sending events from Winform application to Universal Analytics via Measurement protocol and I use fiddler to inspect the request and response. Everything seems to be OK, but no events appears in Universal Analytics.

My app request:

```
POST http://www.google-analytics.com/collect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com
Content-Length: 112
Expect: 100-continue

v=1
&tid=UA-44974825-1
&cid=1aba0888-732f-4690-9a91-d906c94a4a23
&t=exception
&exd=NullReferenceException
&exf=1
```

Server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 07 Aug 1995 23:30:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Last-Modified: Sun, 17 May 1998 03:00:00 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: image/gif
Date: Fri, 18 Oct 2013 13:54:39 GMT
Server: Golfe2
Content-Length: 35
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic

GIF89a�����������,�������D�;
```

Comment: Parameter "t" = exception means there was a problem with your request formation. Are you getting any JS errors or anything in the console? What does your code look like that is calling UA? If all else fails, try using the debug version of the code, http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js

Comment: @MisterPhilip `t=exception` is in the request.  It **does not** mean there was a problem with the request.  He's logging an exception to Google Analytics using the new measurement protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your request is missing the app name parameter, &an, which is required for sending data to app profiles in Google Analytics via the Measurement Protocol.

The requirements for sending app data to Google Analytics via the Measurement Protocol are documented here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#apptracking

The GA endpoint will **always return 200**, even if the request is missing required parameters.

Comment: I suppose, the app name parameter is for mobile app tracking (t=appview), I use Exception tracking (t=exception), I have the identical parameters like in the exception tracking example.

Comment: Currently, hits with t=exception will only be reported in app profiles, so you would need to also use the app name parameter.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but trying to track an event (t=event). I tried adding the &an parameter, but it's still not registering the event. It does work with pageviews hits.

Comment: I think I solved the problem, but not sure what it was. I was either forgetting to add the client id (cid) parameter, or it didn't like the one that I was sending.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered another reason why no data is being collected: I hadn't upgraded my property to **Universal Analytics**, yet! Doh!

Answer (score 1):

The root problem here is that you are not formatting your request properly.  You need to format your POST body like any other `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded POST body, all on one line:

```
v=1&tid=UA-44974825-1&cid=1aba0888-732f-4690-9a91-d906c94a4a23&t=exception&exd=NullReferenceException&exf=1
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who lands here looking for solution to something similar, check this tool: [Hit builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) to validate the payload data.
I was facing the same issue this tool helped.

(Not sure if this debug tool was available then when this question was posted)